# How to create an AWS AMI from a .out file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ami

I'm setting up a new infrastructure on AWS and I need to deploy loadbalanced firewalls.

I bought FortiGate licences (6.0.6) but there is no official (from Fortinet provider) AMI available for this version.

I've downloaded the .out file from the Fortinet website that contains the FortiGate firmware related to my license and now I need to create my own AMI from this .out file.

So I've tried putting the .out file in a S3 object and use this S3 to create an AMI. But I need a manifest from this S3 to create a new AMI which I apparently do not possess (I can't find it).

How can I use this .out file to create a, private, AWS AMI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **Amazon Machine Image (AMI)** can be created from an Amazon EC2 instance:

- **Launch** an Amazon EC2 instance using a normal AMI (eg Amazon Linux, or whatever one you want)
- **Install** software and **configure** the instance as you desire
- Choose **Create Image** to create an AMI from the Amazon EC2 instance

You might find some software relating to creating bundled images from S3, but that is for something older called Instance Store-backed AMIs. You don't want to use them these days.

Comment: Actually I've clicked on the AMI for the 6.2.1 in the market place and it was possible to choose an other version of the solution on this page : https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/server/procurement?productId=e5936f4a-0d69-479f-919c-d5e158bd4d12
Thank you for your answer it was, in any case, pretty good :)
Have a nice day :)